I need to remove a single line break at the start of a generated document
I created a script (with the help of chatGPT) that uses the data from a spreadsheet in order to create a bunch of certificates, based on a template certificate I have.
The script works perfectly. Except, for the life of me, I cannot figure out why there is one extra line break in the beginning of the generated document. I have it so they all become one document, for ease of printing. But the first certificate at the top always has one extra line break, which would make it not print along the lines of the paper we have.
My question is, is there a single line of code that can be added to just take the document at the end and just delete a single line break?
I know I can just manually delete one thing every time i generate a certificate list, but the problem is i'm making this for some people who are even more computer illiterate, and I need to make this as easy as possible for them.
ChatGPT's most recent suggestion was something like using a line like this
allCertificatesBody.setText(content.substring(1));

but for some reason, this absolutely destroys the formatting of all the certificates. They all have to have specific spacing and fonts in order to fit in the blanks of the certificate paper. This line of code changed all the spacing and changed the fonts back to Arial size 11.
This is my code below:
function generateCertificates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Master");
  var templateId = '1JqoZVyfEh6UZNeEmTIC1rTe04PSu7WhM3KFozDkOBvQ'; // Template document ID
  var dateValue = formatDate(sheet.getRange("AB1").getValue()); // Date from cell AB1 formatted as "MMMM dd yyyy"

  // Get all data from columns B, C, D, and J
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B2:J" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  // Create the final document
  var allCertificatesDoc = DocumentApp.create(dateValue + " certificates");
  var allCertificatesBody = allCertificatesDoc.getBody();

  // Set the final document to landscape and set margins to 0
  allCertificatesBody.setPageHeight(612).setPageWidth(792); // 792x612 is landscape
  allCertificatesBody.setMarginTop(0).setMarginBottom(0).setMarginLeft(0).setMarginRight(0);

  var firstCertificate = true;

  // Loop through the data to find rows with true in column J
  for (var i = 0; i < dataRange.length; i++) {
    if (dataRange[i][8] === true) { // Check if the checkbox in column J is checked
      var firstName = dataRange[i][0];
      var lastName = dataRange[i][1];
      var promotionDetails = dataRange[i][2].split(' ');
      var firstPart = promotionDetails[0];
      var secondPart = promotionDetails.slice(1).join(' ');
      var fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;

      // Open the template document
      var templateDoc = DocumentApp.openById(templateId);
      var templateBody = templateDoc.getBody();

      // Create a temporary document to hold the modified content
      var tempDoc = DocumentApp.create('Temp Doc');
      var tempBody = tempDoc.getBody();

      // Copy the template content to the temporary document
      copyBodyContent(templateBody, tempBody);

      // Replace placeholders with actual data in the temporary document
      tempBody.replaceText('{{Full_Name}}', fullName)
             .replaceText('{{Promotion_First_Part}}', firstPart)
             .replaceText('{{Promotion_Second_Part}}', secondPart)
             .replaceText('{{Date}}', dateValue);

      // Append the modified content to the final document without introducing extra line breaks
      if (!firstCertificate) {
        allCertificatesBody.appendPageBreak();
      } else {
        firstCertificate = false;
      }

      // Append paragraphs from the temporary document to the final document
      copyBodyContent(tempBody, allCertificatesBody);

      // Delete the temporary document
      DriveApp.getFileById(tempDoc.getId()).setTrashed(true);
    }
  }

  // Save the final document with the correct name
  var finalDocFile = DriveApp.getFileById(allCertificatesDoc.getId());
  finalDocFile.setName(dateValue + " certificates");
}

// Helper function to format the date as "MMMM dd yyyy"
function formatDate(date) {
  return Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMMM dd yyyy");
}

// Helper function to copy body content from one document to another
function copyBodyContent(sourceBody, targetBody) {
  var totalElements = sourceBody.getNumChildren();
  for (var i = 0; i < totalElements; i++) {
    var element = sourceBody.getChild(i).copy();
    targetBody.appendParagraph(element);
  }
}


The following code removes the first paragraph of the active document.
function removeFirstParagraph() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const body = doc.getBody();
  const paragraph_1 = body.getParagraphs()[0]
  body.removeChild(paragraph_1);
}

You might include an adaptation of the above to your script after the first certificate is appended.
Remove
else {
    firstCertificate = false;
}

After
// Delete the temporary document
DriveApp.getFileById(tempDoc.getId()).setTrashed(true);

and before the next } add
if(firstCertificate){
    allCertificatesBody.removeChild(body.getParagraphs()[0]);
    firstCertificate = false;
}

